# Как использовать android методы в libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Создал приложение на основе библиотеки libgdx. В итоге у меня получилось несколько проектов(android, html, ios,desctop, и core). Итоговая программа пишется под Андроид, например, как мне вызвать какой-либо метод из проекта Андроид, например, при нажатии на актера вызвать метод который что либо запишет в базу данных.

Мэйн активити Андроид проекта:
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    }

Мэйн класс Core проекта:
public class MainClass extends Game {
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ссылке есть решение этой проблемы:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code